# Block incoming HTTP/S traffic from a list of IPs in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

So far we have been blocking incoming traffic by inputting manually a suspected attacker IP directly into the AWS web app, using the network ACL inbound rules interface:

[image]

This is great because it blocks the traffic before it gets to our application. The problem is tho that we need to input each new IP manually. Is there a way to import a list/csv to block? Or maybe a script somewhere we can run to add the ips?

Comment: This approach simply isn't gonna work. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/amazon-vpc-limits.html "Rules per network ACL: 20"

Comment: @ceejayoz good to know, thank! It seems then the only option is to block the traffic in the web server

Comment: AWS WAF can also block traffic based on IP lists, and I suspect you can have a lot more entries than a NACL. You can probably work out some kind of a script that uses the CLI to add them. You could also use IPTables on the instance, or something like fail2ban to automate it. Fail2ban is quite configurable, I have it calling out to CloudFlare firewall to add a rule to block an IP before it reaches the server, you could probably do the same with AWS WAF.

Answer (score 2):

A better option is to use [AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/), which gives you more flexibility and more rules. WAF integrates with a load balancer or CloudFront, but not with IP addresses.

You can probably automate adding IPs to the WAF using Fail2Ban. I [integrated Fail2Ban with CloudFlare](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/aws-amazon-web-services/protecting-amazon-linux-server-fail2ban-cloudflare-wordpress/), you might find a similar article for AWS WAF.